# Change layout background color of listview item when is selected in MULTIPLE CHOICE MODE

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to use in listSelector, but state_selected and state_checked are not working as I thought. I have also tried to use the selector in android:background tag on the list item XML, but it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way in your activity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View clickedView,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (clickedView.getId()) {

            case R.id.itemLayoutId:
              lytBackground = (LinearLayout) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutId);
              lytBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0e95cf"));
              break;
```

Here lytBackground is parent layout of your listView row item.

To have feature like on first click row is selected and on second click (on same row) it gets unselected, save clickedView in a global variable

```
private View clickedView;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View clickedView,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (clickedView.getId()) {

            case R.id.itemLayoutId:

              if (this.clickedView == clickedView ) {
                lytBackground = (LinearLayout) this.clickedView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutId);
                lytBackground .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3eb4d8")); //normal color
            }
            lytBackground = (LinearLayout) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.itemLayoutId);
            lytBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0e95cf")); // selected color
            this.clickedView = clickedView;
              break;
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I think that this is possible by XML, but this is not a bad solution ;)